# Cannot connect to MSSQL database using jdbc

Tags: java, android, sql-server-2008

I'm trying to run a simple Android application that has a button click event which connects to database and retrieves a user from Clients table depending on the text input.

```
   Class.forName("com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver"); 
        Connection  connection = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:sqlserver://ServerUrl;databaseName=DBNAME;selectMethod=cursor;user=USER;password=*****");

 Statement statement = connection.createStatement();  
 ResultSet resultSet = statement.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM Clients WHERE IMEI = "+imei+"");
```

However, when I run the project with a breakpoint on the line that begins with "Statement" I notice that the code does not event arrive at that line.

I tried surrounding the connection line with try-catch but it throws no exception, it simply does nothing. The database is hosted so it's not on localhost.

Please keep in mind that I'm very new to Android development and do not burn me if I'm missing something very simple :)

Comment: If you set a breakpoint at the first line and step line by line, where does it crash?

Comment: It must work, i do the same in my j2ee app, perhaps dont put "user" and "password" in the code.

Comment: That's the thing , it does not crash. I tried setting the breakpoint to the connection line and used step into but there was no crash or exception anywhere.

Comment: Could it be an issue that the database is not at localhost but the application is?

Comment: @CanCanbek How far can you step?

Comment: I'm not sure exactly I seem to be able to step into it for a very long time, it steps into the classes that come with the library then honestly after like two hundred steps I got bored and just clicked continue, but then again, no errors or exceptions. The farthest I've gone to was when it started reading the server address character by character.